# RxSwift MVVM How to Set up View Model With Item Manager?

Tags: swift, rx-swift

**Say I have the following [SwiftRx](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxSwift) (2.0.0-beta.4) [MVVM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93viewmodel) situation:**

I have 4 things:

- ItemListViewController
- ItemsViewModel
- ItemsManager
- Item

**ItemsManager** has a func called **items()** that will return Items in an observable RxSwift way.

**ItemsViewModel** only needs to pass the items on up for now. Later maybe apply display logic on an Item attribute for the View Controller's sake (like displaying a date correctly.)

**ItemListViewController** will put the items in a table, one Item per row.

An Item has 4 attributes (like an identifier, date, ...) that will be displayed in the table row cell.

**How does one set it up in the ItemsViewModel and ItemsManager so that when items are added, removed, changed in the manager that they go through the ItemsViewModel?**

From reading the [documentation](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxSwift/blob/master/Documentation/Subjects.md) and looking at the [Rx.playground](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxSwift), it seems like the thing to use for now is an RxSwift **PublishSubject< Item >** or maybe an RxSwift **map** that is somehow subscribed to the manager's items()

How to do this well?

The ItemsManager has something like this right now:

```
func items() -> Observable<Item> {
    // placeholder for now
    return [Item(identification: "123", content: ""), Item(identification: "456", content:""), Item(identification: "789", content:"")].toObservable()
}
```

The View Model has this in it:

```
let items = Variable(/* how to subsribe to the items in the manager? */)
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A contrived solution aka something which demonstrates a general approach and is simpler to understand is below:

```
import UIKit
import RxSwift
import RxCocoa

struct Item {

    let identification: String
    let content: String
}

struct ItemsManager {

    let items: Variable<[Item]> = Variable<[Item]>(
        [Item(identification: "some id1", content: "some content"),
        Item(identification: "some id2", content: "some more content")]
    )
}

struct ItemsViewModel {

    let itemsManager = ItemsManager()

    let myItems:Observable<[String]>

    init() {

        myItems = itemsManager.items
        .map({ someArrayOfItems in
            return someArrayOfItems.map {$0.content }
        })
    }
}

class ItemListViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!

    let itemsViewModel = ItemsViewModel()

    let disposeBag = DisposeBag()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        itemsViewModel.myItems
            .bindTo(tableView.rx_itemsWithCellIdentifier("itemListCell")) { (row, element, cell) in

                guard let myCell: UITableViewCell = cell else {
                    return
                }

                myCell.textLabel?.text = element
            }
            .addDisposableTo(disposeBag)

    }
}
```